# PowerShell - Find AD users with specific AD attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello and Greetings to anyone paying attention to the post.
As always, Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated and i do not take your help for granted.
You guys ( and gals ) are Lifesavers.

I have a csv sheet , filled with different VALUES, which are set to a PRATICULAR custom ATTTRIBUTE my users have. Lets call this value, "costumattribute".

I have done a test with this PS line using one of the attribute VALUES from the csv :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'costumattribute -like "+999999999"' | Select-Object samaccountname
```

Running this line, indeed gave me the desired result, presenting the **SamAccountName** of the user
Which has the value "+999999999" set in the "costumattribute" he has.

I would like to continue the command script based on the following requirements:

- Values should be read from csv ( Import-CSV ) . The Csv will contain the following:
  Column A: different "costumattribute" values, listed throughout the column.

From this actions, i would like , a CSV file exported, containing the following data:

- SamAccount Name, for each user, matching the "costumattribute" found, from  each particular line
  in Column A , on the imported CSV FILE.
- IMPORTANT - i need the exported file , to add BLANK line in the exported csv for each unfound value.
  And not SKIP IT, so that the exported csv file, will contain exactly the same number of
  Lines as the imported csv, for later comparisons.

Thank you all !

Comment: As for you last _IMPORTANT_ rquirement: What if multiple users have that custom attribute value? Should all of these users end up in the same `SamAccountName` column in the output or on separate record lines?. If the latter, the resulting CSV will probably have more lines than the original input file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using the `-like` operator without [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) will do the same as `-eq`.

If your csv input file looks anything like this:

```
ColumnA,ColumnB
-6666666,BlahBlah
+7777777,BlahBlahBlah
-8888888,BlahBlahBlahBlah
+9999999,BlahBlahBlahBlahBlah
```

Then something like below would result in a csv file I think you want:

```
$attribute = 'costumattribute' 
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\attributes.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $attribValue = $_.ColumnA
    $accountName = (Get-ADUser -Filter "$attribute -eq '$attribValue'" -Properties $attribute).SamAccountName
    "" | Select-Object @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$accountName -join '; '}},
                       @{Name = $attribute; Expression = {$attribValue}}
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\users_attributes.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello Theo, i am not getting any results in the OUTPUT csv file. one thing i didn't mentioned, is it possible due to a conflict with EXCEL .CSV type files working with "+" values ? as mentioned, my attribute contain "+". also, i was thinking of trying an alternative using a TXT file, can we try a get-content syntax for using a txt file? regarding duplicate question, the only duplicate i can think of here is the BLANK./null. i wouldn't worry about that much for now. i will update if i will think its necessary to deal with this.

Comment: @sj1986 Are you getting any error messages on `Get-ADUser`?. Excel can do strange things with values like `+999999` on import. To force Excel to treat those as text, you can either prepend an apostrophe `'` or a TAB character ``"`t"`` to them

Comment: Hi again, excuse me for, lack of knowledge but, maybe i miss understood, where should i have the value name, i changed on the first line " $attribute = 'costumattribute' " in this one, i just inserted the attribute name i actually wish to use, but is there anywhere else in the code i should change to my own value aswell?

Comment: @sj1986 Well, only the paths for `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` of course. Then, if your input csv file has a different column header for the attribute value to fetch, you should change that accordingly. (`ColumnA` is just an example, so use the _real_ column name). Also, if the real column header has spaces in it, you need to quote it as in `$_.'Column A'`

Comment: Its working . Thank you. i changed the first column header name to "ColumnA', and used " ' "character before every value with "+" in its beginning as you have suggested. The only the issue is, excel acting out, by giving something like "9.72557E+11" in the output file, on column b. when i select the cell, i can see in the formula box the actual number is there tough. anyway to fix is so that it will show the actual value in  a normal way?

Comment: One more thing here -  i noticed , for one of my users , the script exported the ALIAS of the user instead of the SAMACCOUNTNAME does that makes sense? any way to make sure the script extract the sam account logon name and not the alias?

Comment: @sj1986 Sorry, really late reply... To have Excel see the attribute value as string and not convert it to a numeric value, prepend a TAB character in front of the value: ``@{Name = $attribute; Expression = {"`t{0}" -f $attribValue}}``.
As for the ALIAS... The code explicitely adds the SamAccountName property, so what is that alias you're talking about?